# I have a csv file and I want to put data into a struct, but I don't know why it retain only the last line

Tags: c, csv, struct

Why is the struct retain only the last line of the file?

```
typedef struct Student
{
    char* nume;
    char* prenume;
    int cod;
    float nota;
}Student;


int fileNrLines(int lines)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("students.csv", "r");

    char ch;
    lines = 0;
    lines++;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (ch == '\n')
            lines++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return lines;
}

void printStudents(Student *myStudents, int size)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("| %20s | %20s | %d | %.2f |\n",
            myStudents[i].nume, myStudents[i].prenume, myStudents[i].cod, myStudents[i].nota);
}

void main()
{

    int lines=0;
    Student *myStudents;
    myStudents = (Student*)malloc(fileNrLines(lines) * sizeof(Student));
    lines = fileNrLines(lines);
    FILE *fp = fopen("students.csv", "r");
    char myLine[50];
    char* myWord;
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    {

        fgets(myLine, 50, fp);
        int contor = 1;
        myWord = strtok(myLine, ",");
        while (myWord!=NULL)

        {

            myStudents[index].nume = myWord;
            //puts(myStudents[i].nume);
            myWord=strtok(NULL, ",");
            contor++;


            myStudents[index].prenume = myWord;
            //puts(myStudents[i].prenume);
            myWord=strtok(NULL, ",");
            contor++;

            int x = atoi(myWord);
            myStudents[index].cod = x;
            //printf(" %d \n",myStudents[i].cod);
            myWord=strtok(NULL, ",");
            contor++;

            float y = atoll(myWord);
            myStudents[index].nota = y;
            //printf(" %.2f \n", myStudents[i].nota);
            myWord=strtok(NULL, ",");
            contor++;

        }
        index++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    printStudents(myStudents, &lines);
}
```

if I print into the while loop is ok but after that not

Comment: `printStudents(myStudents, &lines);` should be `printStudents(myStudents, lines);` (no `&` before `lines`).

Comment: Recommendation/question: why do you pass a parameter to `fileNrLines(lines)`? How can you prevent having to count the lines twice?

Comment: And why do you have a `while(myWord!=NULL)` loop in which `index` doesn't change? What happens if `myLine` has more commas than you expect? For that matter, what happens if it contains fewer commas than you expect? Do you know what `strtok` returns if it doesn't find the comma?

Comment: `char ch;` -> `int ch;`. `fgetc` returns an `int`. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that (for example this line)

```
myStudents[index].nume = myWord;
```

doesn't populate `nume` with a new and unique string. Instead, it's simply assigning the memory location that `myWord` is currently pointing to. Since this is the first token on each line, it'll always likely be pointing to the start of `myLine` so each `nume` will be identical. For other columns, the position of `myWord` will be different so you'll get rather more unexpected results.

Instead you want to create a new string each time, like this.

```
myStudents[index].nume = strdup(myWord);
```

Or

```
myStudents[index].nume = malloc(strlen(myWord)+1);
strcpy(myStudents[index].nume,myWord);
```

You will need to remember to `free()` this memory that has been allocated.